# How to fix java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core

Tags: android

While adding some gradle dependency, getting error

**Exception was raised by workers: java.lang.RuntimeException:**

```
**Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine found in modules** kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)
  Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.Active found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)
  Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AwaitAll found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)
  Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AwaitAll$AwaitAllNode found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add your gradle files

Comment: updated that in answer

Comment: seems like there is duplicated dependency in your gradle file,

Comment: @GiritejaBille. There was no duplicate dependency when added  a new dependency then only  this error   occured and fixed when just update gradle url

Comment: okay , if the error got resolved , please mark the question as resolved ,it would help other peers not to look at the question in view of answering it .

Comment: @GiritejaBille it will be allowed to mark own answer after 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be resolved by

Android Studio project gradle url updated from
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.+-all.zip
to
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.+-all.zip

have fixed this issue